# Creating a payment request without 'basic-card' fails

Tags: payment-request-api

I'm trying to create an integration to Google Pay via the payment request api.  This all works fine until I remove `basic-card` from the supported methods.

I get `Unexpected developer error.`

Does anyone know how to create a payment request without `basic-card`?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a code sample you use?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this.  Turns out it was an issue with the code I was using to set up with Google Pay

Comment: Could you specify what the issue was, at all?

Comment: I was setting up a test integration to demo to someone, I didn't realize that the `parameters` needed to contain details and not just an empty object as it is on the https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/paymentrequest/tutorial

Comment: Thanks. That looks like an older version of the API than I'm using, but I'll have a closer look at what's going on with the parameters object when I get this error.